# Excel conditional formatting does not format anything

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight the row which has the today's date. I am using the condition

```
=$B20=TODAY()
```

with the format applied to the whole table, but not even a cell is highlighted (B20 is the cell which contains the content '31.1.17', and it IS a date, not text or something. The Weekday is in a separate column):

[image]

How to fix the expression? What is wrong?

Comment: is B20 actaully a date? did you manually right align it? Because I tested it with date at the same formula is working for me.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to change the Formula to `=DATEVALUE($B3)=TODAY()` or `=DATEDIF($B3;TODAY();"d")=0`

Comment: Does B20 contain only the date?  Perhaps there is also a time but it is formatted to show just the date.

Comment: Yes, B20 contains only the date. i.e. '31.01.17'. The weekday is in column 'A'...

Comment: Your formula should work.  There is something else going on.  If you format B20 as `General`, what do you see?

Comment: The date is now a number, as expected, but no formatting anywhere ...

Comment: I am not sure what I have changed, but its working now with the original(!) formula. I changed the format, I changed to left-align, I have inserted the equation `=$B20=TODAY()` which got changed by some magic to `=$B39=TODAY()`, I fix the cell in the equation, then it worked....

Comment: Select B20 again on your worksheet, and see if the formula still refers to B20, using the CF Manager

Comment: Now its 'B9'...

Comment: What is going on...?

Comment: @Alex You need to recreate the rule, with $B20 selected at the time you create the rule.  With other than an absolute address, the address being referenced will change in relation to the (in this case) row 20 vs the row you have selected.  So just recreate the rule **after** selecting B20, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the formula to : `=DATEDIF($B3;TODAY();"d")=0`

(For the first cell of your range, so that i'll be `=DATEDIF($B20;TODAY();"d")=0` for row 20)

Comment: Yes, funny, the FIRST row (row 3) is formatted now, although I have used 'B20' in the formula (checked three times...)

Comment: @Alex : Sometimes, Conditional Formating is smart, so if I understand, you used `=DATEDIF($B20;TODAY();"d")=0` on row 3? And the formatting isn't on the good row? Best thing is to click outside of your range edit the rule from the Rules Manager, by selecting the `This WorkSheet`

Comment: I think I used the formatting on the correct row. But who knows what excel does...

Comment: @Alex : Try to delete the rule and recreate it from scratch with `=DATEDIF($B3;TODAY();"d")=0`

Comment: @Alex : Your row in the formula should be the first row of the range in which you want to apply the conditional formatting (for what you are trying to achieve). Does it work with this?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how. I tried it again and then suddenly it worked, without having changed anything (I know of). Not sure what happened. Maybe a glitch in excel...?

Comment: @Alex : If you didn't change anything it's a bit strange indeed... Some times, a simple change in the sheet triggers a recaculation of the conditional formatting. Glad it worked anyway!